# mesos master deactivates agent when a pod is deployed through marathon

Tags: mesos, marathon

I have a single node mesos master set up. When I deploy an application through Marathon WebUI, it works fine.

But when I deploy a pod by using the marathon API, the mesos master immediately deactivates the agent and pod creation gets stuck.

Per documentation, I cannot deploy a pod through the Marathon Web. It can only be deployed using the API.

Given below is the slave log:

> Log file created at: 2018/09/23 17:20:37 Running on machine:
>   centos-4vcpu-8gb-01 Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu
>   threadid file:line] msg E0923 17:20:37.561741 19267 slave.cpp:4512]
>   Failed to handle status update acknowledgement (UUID:
>   7f42cf82-8b1f-4ab5-8cff-0beb917efa3f) for task
>   stubgen-db-pod.instance-ef81f6b3-bf54-11e8-88d8-0242845a02ba.stubgen-db-container
>   of framework b606e9e2-b9ef-4b09-9b7d-3f6d0489bf58-0000: Cannot find
>   the task status update stream for task
>   stubgen-db-pod.instance-ef81f6b3-bf54-11e8-88d8-0242845a02ba.stubgen-db-container
>   of framework b606e9e2-b9ef-4b09-9b7d-3f6d0489bf58-0000

Sometimes, it displays "not a valid container" and "container not found"

I am able to launch the container using docker cli.

Can someone let me know what could be the cause?

Pasting below my pod definition:

```
{
    "id": "stubgen-db-pod",
    "containers": [
        {
            "name": "stubgen-db-container",
            "resources": {
                "cpus": 0.5,
                "mem": 1024
            },
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "name": "stubgen-db",
                    "containerPort": 27017,
                    "hostPort": 0,
                    "protocol": [
                        "tcp"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "image": {
                "kind": "DOCKER",
                "id": "<image_from_docker_repo>"
            },
            "healthCheck":{
                "http":{
                   "endpoint":"httpendpoint",
                   "path":"/ping",
                   "scheme":"HTTP"
                },
                "gracePeriodSeconds":30,
                "intervalSeconds":5,
                "maxConsecutiveFailures":3,
                "timeoutSeconds":3,
                "delaySeconds":2
            },
            "volumeMounts":[
                {
                   "name":"dbvolume",
                   "mountPath":"/data/db"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "volumes":[
        {
          "name":"dbvolume"
        }
    ],
    "networks":[
      {
         "name":"dcos",
         "mode":"container"
      }
    ],
    "scaling":{
      "kind":"fixed",
      "instances":1,
      "maxInstances":null
    },
    "scheduling": {
      "backoff":{
         "backoff":1,
         "backoffFactor":1.15,
         "maxLaunchDelay":3600
      },
      "upgrade":{
         "minimumHealthCapacity":1,
         "maximumOverCapacity":1
      },
      "unreachableStrategy": {
         "inactiveAfterSeconds":900,
         "expungeAfterSeconds":604800
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the format tools provided to format your post, i.e. use the button `{}` to format your code part.

Comment: can you post the mesos task stderr or/and stdout snippet? Not the slave.log